# Is it safe to enable fast boot in Windows 8 while mounting windows partition as read-only in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, ntfs

It is dangerous to write on NTFS partition while Windows uses hybrid boot because there is a potential risk of data loss. So I tried to mount Windows 8 partition as read-only in Ubuntu, now I wonder if it is safe to access the partition in Ubuntu or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is dangerous to write on NTFS partition while Windows uses hybrid boot

Ubuntu will refuse to mount an unsafe NTFS partition writable. So it is not a matter of "dangerous"; it is a matter of Ubuntu not letting you.

If you would be able to write to it the next time you boot into Windows those changes would be gone. That is what you would call "data loss".

> now I wonder if it is safe to access the partition in Ubuntu or not?

As read only it is safe. You can not alter the disk so when Windows boots the disk it is as it was when it was hibernated.